# Finding nearest element in a set of integers

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I have following problem to solve:

Given N integers forming set S and another integer A (not neccesarily same as any of the N integers given), find integer from set S that is nearest to integer A.

I first thought this is a NNS (nearest neighbor Search) problem, but in NNS, integer A must be from set S as well, which in my case it doesn't have to be.

Then I thought of putting each integer from S into a binary search tree and searching for first occurence where one of children is smaller than query and parent is bigger than query, but I don't know if this will work.

Which data structure should I use? Thank you.

EDIT: forgot to mention I need this to be better than O(n), O(logn) is good enough. Thus I can't use linear search.

Comment: Is your set sorted or not?

Comment: If there's only one `A`, what's wrong with linear search?

Comment: @PulkitGoyal Yes, it is sorted. Btw, forgot to mention I'd need this in O(logn). Gonna edit my question now.

Comment: Just a sorted array/list with binary search?

Comment: binary search for number less than or equal to A, just compare this and its next number for which would be nearest. handle corner cases too.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko integer A isn't neccesarily from the set S (same as any of N integers), for example S might be {1, 4, 9}, and A might be 3. Did you mean some variation of binary search?

Comment: @leonz you can do a binary search in that case.

Comment: I didn't think of modifying binary search to get this, but yes, this is what I need. Someone say this in an answer so I can mark it as accepted.

Comment: @leonz: it's quite OK for binary search to return an interval, e.g. `[1..4]` in your case; then you check the borders: `1` and `3` as well as `4` and `3`

Comment: @leonz: see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y15ef976(v=vs.110).aspx as typical binary search implementation: you have either an exact hit (positive value) or a closest item (negative output)

Comment: Read this : https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/binary-search/ You will really learn binary search enough to modify it how you want and get good knowledge of using binary search

Comment: Thank you very much guys, I really appreciate all the help. Again, someone can put this into an actual answer if you want points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is a typical input for a *binary search* within a sorted array/list. The only difficulty is to be aware of *four* cases (see them my C# implementation). Binary search can often be found as a part of a standard library, in C# case

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y15ef976(v=vs.110).aspx

```
private static int Closest(int[] S, int A) {
  int index = Array.BinarySearch(S, A);

  if (index >= 0)
    return S[index];        // exact match, A in S
  else if (index == -1)
    return S[0];            // A is less than any item in S
  else if (index < -S.Length)
    return S[S.Length - 1]; // A is greater than any item in S
  else {                    // A is in [left..right] range
    // C# specific range encoding; consult your languages/library manual   
    int left = ~index - 1;
    int right = ~index;

    if (Math.Abs(S[left] - A) < Math.Abs(S[right] - A))
      return S[left];
    else
      return S[right];
  }
```

Tests:

```
  int[] array = new[] { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 };

  // 10
  Console.Write(Closest(array, 11));
  // 20
  Console.Write(Closest(array, 19));
  // 10
  Console.Write(Closest(array, 4));
  // 50
  Console.Write(Closest(array, 400));
  // 30
  Console.Write(Closest(array, 30));
```

Answer (score 0):

If the set is sorted, you can easily modify binary search to find the nearest integer in `O(log n)`. You can imagine, that you are looking for a place in the set where to put the number, so it remains sorted. Once you have found it with binary search (in C++ you can use `lower_bound` for this), you just check which number is closer - the one before or the one after.

Answer (score 0):

Since the list is already sorted, treat is as the problem of placing a new element in the list maintaining the sort order. Once the location (say i th position), is finalized, calculate the delta from S[i-1] and S[i+1], to get the nearest integer to A.